# Rate of Convergence of a sequence of functions

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, convergence-divergence, fourier-analysis, rate-of-convergence

I know that the rate of convergence $\mu$ of a convergent sequence $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb N} \to x$ in $\mathbb R$ is given by 
$$\mu = \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{|x_{n+1} - x|}{|x_n - x|}.$$
But if I have a sequence of functions $(f_n(x))_{n\in\mathbb N} \to f(x)$, is there an analogous way one can determine the rate at which $f_n$ converges to $f$? In particular, I am interested in the Fourier series $f_n, g_n : [0,1] \to \mathbb R$ given by

$$ f_n(x) = - \sum_{k = 1}^n \frac{2(-1)^k}{k\pi} \sin (k\pi x) \qquad \text{and} \qquad g_n(x) = \frac{1}{2} + \sum_{k = 1}^n\frac{2((-1)^k-1)}{k^2 \pi^2} \cos (k\pi x)$$

where both $f_n$ and $g_n$ converge to $f(x) = x$ for $x\in [0,1]$.

Experimentally (through [different plots for different values of $n$](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X3LtR.png)), I know that $f_n$ converges to $f$ more slowly than $g_n$ does, but I do not know how to prove this rigorously. I appreciate any assistance.

Comment: Well, I can see a problem there, as equality $g(x)=f(x)=x$ only exist on the limit $x\in [0,1]$. The Fourier series describe a periodic function, not a 1st order/linear one.

Comment: @JHBonarius But I only want to show convergence in that interval (that is, on the domain of $f_n$, $g_n$. Why should that be a problem?

Comment: I'm not sure that will work. Maybe if you integrate? $\mu = \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\int_0^1(|f_{n+1}(x) - x|)dx}{\int_0^1(|f_n(x) - x|)dx}$

Comment: @JHBonarius In that case, I think it should be $$ \mu = \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{\int_0^1 |f_{n+1}(x) - f(x)|\, \mathrm{d}x}{\int_0^1 |f_n(x) - f(x)|\, \mathrm{d}x}.$$ But how could we interpret the limit as a measure of rate of convergence?

Comment: No, I don't think so. You state you want to determine the distance/error from $f_n(x)$ to $lim_{n\to\infty}f_n(x)=x$, which is given by $|f_n(x)-x|$. What you'd expect is that $\mu_g<\mu_f$, i.e. $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\int_0^1|g_{n+1}(x)-x|dx}{\int_0^1|g_{n}(x)-x|dx}<\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\int_0^1|f_{n+1}(x)-x|dx}{\int_0^1|f_{n}(x)-x|dx}$$

Comment: @JHBonarious Yes you're right, I meant $f(x)$ in general, but yes in this case $f(x) = x$.

Comment: ah, true, because you defined $f(x)=\lim_{n\to\infty}f_n(x)$ to be so. We're on the same page. By the way, I'm not posting an answer, as I'm not sure about my theory. It could be that there's a better way to do it. My theory is: the rate of convergence is determined by the change in distance/error from one $n$ to the next. My suggested formula does that for $f_n(x)$. It might be challenging to solve analytically, maybe requiring Taylor expansion.

Comment: From my point of view the natural thing to do is $\mu:=lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{\lVert f_{n+1}-f\rVert_{\infty,[0,1]}}{\lVert f_{n}-f\rVert_{\infty,[0,1]}}$, since you have some standard estimates relating uniform convergence of fourier series, and the derivative of the function you are expanding. integrating from my poin of view sounds quite weird.

Comment: @Diesirae92 Can you please define $\lVert f \rVert$?

Comment: It is the standard norm of uniform convergence on $[0,1]$

Comment: You can consider the quotient $\frac{d(x_{n+1},x)}{d(x_n,x)}$ in every metric space as a measure of the rate of convergence. That has been done for $L^1([0,1])$ and for $L^{\infty}([0,1])$ here in the comments. However, for Fourier series $L^2$ seems to be the natural choice, and the orthogonality of the systems makes it easy to see that $\lVert f_n - \operatorname{id}\rVert_{L^2} \sim c_1 \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$ and $\lVert g_n - \operatorname{id}\rVert_{L^2} \sim c_2 \frac{1}{n^{3/2}}$.

Comment: It is also worth noting that $(g_n)$ converges uniformly, but $(f_n)$ doesn't. That's because $(g_n)$ is the Fourier series of the even extension $\lvert x\rvert$ to $[-1,1]$, whose $2$-periodic extension is Lipschitz continuous, while $(f_n)$ is the Fourier series of the odd extension $x$ to $[-1,1]$ whose $2$-periodic extension has a jump disctontinuity at the odd integers. (See also Gibbs' phenomenon.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've decided to try and answer my own question. First of all, as has been mentioned in the comments, $f_n \to f$ only pointwise, whereas $g \to f$  uniformly. This already indicates that $g_n$ converges more strongly.

Now treating $f$ and $g$ as two elements of the function space $\mathbb R ^ {[0,1]}$ with the $L^2$ norm $$\left\| \phi \right\| = \int_0^1 |\phi(x)|^2 \,\mathrm d x,$$
    we define the rate of convergence of $\phi_n$ to $\phi$ by
    $$\mu_{\phi_n,\,\phi} = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\left\| \phi_{n+1}-\phi \right\|}{\left\| \phi_n - \phi \right\|}.$$

What we want to show is that $\mu_{f_n,\,f} < \mu_{g_n, \, f}$.  Using [Paversal's identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parseval%27s_theorem), we have that
    $$ \|\phi\|^2 = \sum_{n} |\alpha_n|^2,$$ where $\alpha_n$ are the Fourier coefficients of $\phi$. In our case, we have
    $$\| f - f_n \|^2 = \sum_{k=n+1}^\infty |\alpha_k|^2 = \sum_{k=n+1}^\infty \frac{|a_k|}{k^2}.$$
    This gives an expression of the form $ (c - H_n^{(2)})/(d - H_n^{(4)})$ where $H_n^{(2)}$ denotes the generalised harmonic number, and c,d are the corresponding $H_\infty$ terms.  So the question boils down to showing that $\sum_k 1/k^2$ converges more slowly than $\sum_k 1/k^4$, which can be done easily using the original definition of rate of convergence.